# Padding on website despite having it at 0px

Tags: javascript, css, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sumatran Orangutan Society</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
</div>
</body>
</html>

@charset "UTF-8";
#container {
    background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 1100px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

I've been having a problem where there is a margin/padding on the left, top and bottom of my page. I've tried setting the margin and padding to 0px but the gap is still there.

Here's a picture showing what I mean,

[image]

Comment: Have you checked that whatever is inside your container also has `0px` padding and margin?

Comment: That is the browser default padding which I think is 8px

Comment: set margin:0,padding:0 on body and html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`body` usually have a margin of 8px. Try this:

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```